# How to remove "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" banner with Selenium and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating a browser using Selenium WebDriver with Node.js. When the Chrome browser runs, it displays the message "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" at the top. I've tried several solutions I found online to remove this banner, but none of them have worked so far.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    let options = new chrome.Options();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    options.set('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation']);
```

I know it's possible to remove this banner because I've used RPA tools built on Selenium that don't display this warning when automating the browser. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to remove this banner? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Node/JS, use this option line to remove the banner:

```js
options.excludeSwitches("enable-automation")
```

Here's a full script example:

```js
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const options = new chrome.Options();

options.excludeSwitches("enable-automation")

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser("chrome")
  .setChromeOptions(options)
  .build();

driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```